# How do I construct a variable query with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the string `s = "users.count()"`

and the `db` object.

How do I combine `db` and `s` such that `print combination(db,s)` prints the total number of users?

I tried `db[s]` and `db+s` and both don't work.

Thanks!

Comment: too less information

Comment: what more information do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/)
1) Initialize your connection first

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
```

2) Select your `db`

```
db = client["db_name"] #replace db_name with your database name
```

3) Run `count()` on your collection. Say, your collection name is `users`

```
print db.users.count()
# OR
print db["users"].count()
```

If you have something like `s = "users.count()"` and want to execute `s`. Try:

```
collection = s.split(".")[0]
function_call = s.split(".")[-1].strip("()")
print getattr(db[collection],function_call)()
```

Comment: The constraint is to use the string "users.count()" and convert that into db.users.count() i know that i can just use the command directly. I am programmatically generating commands so i need to be able to use variable strings to build up a command

Comment: i eventually used an ugly if elif elif elif chain but im hoping theres something better

Comment: hmm interesting wouldn't have thought to do this ha ill try it out!